# Why running Java UI without SUDO breaks GUI appearance?

Tags: java, linux, swing, ubuntu, sudo

Why running application with SUDO changes GUI appearance?

I.e.Button background, Button size, JTree appearance are behaving differently depending on how the GUI was started with SUDO or not.

Will appreciate your suggestions.
Thank you

Comment: Are you using Button or JButton? Which LaF are you using? The only thing I've noticed is that when I start my program with sudo `UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` returns Metal instead of GTK.

Comment: This is most likely a problem with file permissions or (library) paths on your operating system that doesn't really have anything to do with Java itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much in the way of detail. Presumably root has paths and/or environment variables set up differently. I would guess that `java -fullversion` and `sudo java -fullversion` will give different results.

Comment: owner@ubuntu:~$ java -fullversion
java full version "1.6.0_0-b16"
owner@ubuntu:~$ sudo java -fullversion
[sudo] password for owner: 
java full version "1.6.0_0-b16"
owner@ubuntu:~$

Comment: My guess, root has access to different (additional) font files that the 'owner' user doesn't.

Comment: @Redbeard So `public class ListFonts { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAllFonts())); }}`

Comment: @user219051 Note that the original version of Java SE 6 has known security vulnerabilities. It is probably a good idea to upgrade to 6u20 or 6u21 (at the time of writing).